# SQL: Total days in a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following formula:

```
"Value1" * 100 * "Total day in a month" * "Value2"
```

I have the following table:

```
ID     Date        Time     Value1     Value2
1      2014-01-01  00:00    10         20
2      2014-01-01  01:00    20         5
```

I want to select a data in a year with only using one parameter which is `Year`.
How can I apply the formula into a query?

The result should be:

```
ID     Date        Time     Value1     Value2   TotalDayinMonth   Result
1      2014-01-01  00:00    10         20       31                620000
2      2014-01-01  01:00    20         5        31                310000
ff.
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding. Can you provide more details and work through a couple rows of what output you're expecting?

Comment: So on row 1 with a date of 2014-01-01, Total day in a month = 31?

Comment: Yes, I just edit the question. So it will calculate the total day in every month. Jan = 31. Feb = 28. Mar = 31. It depends on how many days in a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the number of days of a given date like this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2014-01-01'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date))
```

And the query:

```
SELECT  ID
        ,[Date]
        ,[Time]
        ,Value1
        ,Value2
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, [Date], DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [Date])) AS TotalDayinMonth
        ,Value1 * 100 * DATEDIFF(DAY, [Date], DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [Date])) * Value2 AS Result
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: This expression does depend on the date not being towards the end of a long month - e.g. if `@date` is `2014-01-31` we discover that January is 28 days long.

Answer (score 1):

This expression will give you the number of days in the month that `date` is in no matter what day it is:

```
datediff(day,
  dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, date),0),
  dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, date)+1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer. You can use `EOMONTH` AND `DAY` function of SQL to get number of days in a month.

```
SELECT  ID
        ,[Date]
        ,[Time]
        ,Value1
        ,Value2
        ,DAY(EOMONTH(Date)) AS TotalDaysInMonth
        ,Value1 * 100 * DAY(EOMONTH(Date)) * Value2 AS Result
FROM TABLENAME
```

Comment: There is no `EOMONTH()` function in SQL Server 2008

Comment: DAY(EOMONTH(Date)) is a good option for those on SQL Sever 2012 or higher

Answer (score 0):

you can check this also.

```
declare @t table (ID  int, Date date, Time time, Value1 int, Value2 int)

insert into @t values (1,'2014-01-01','00:00',10,20 ) ,  (2,'2014-01-01','00:00',20,5 ),  (3,'2014-02-01','00:00',20,5 )

select * from @t

; with cte as
(
    select id,
        day(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATE)+1,0))) Totaldayofmonth      
    from @t
)
--select * from cte
select 
    *, Value1 * 100 * Totaldayofmonth * Value2
from 
    @t t inner join cte on cte.ID = t.id
```